# C# refresh page sections

Tags: c#, refresh, updatepanel

I have a page that is processing data. It goes through a series of 10 steps. I want the page to display a status after each step. ie. after step 1 data processing done print "Step 1 done" then after step 2 data processing done add text "Step 2 done" etc. How can I do this using only C# without hard postbacks? Or do I have to use AJAX/Javascript or page postbacks?

I've been playing around with updatepanels. One around the whole set of steps. Or an updatepanel around each step and then calling button clicks pro grammatically. The only result I can get is for all the text to display at one time at the end of processing.

I've been racking my brain and have search google endlessly. Hopefully someone out there has an idea for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using ajax -

**Server Side**: 
up a new action method on your server (assuming it's MVC), use this action method to query the state of the task.

```
public string QueryStatus()
{
    return Session["progress"].ToString();
}
```

When the task progresses to the next step, update a variable to indicate this (in database, or session).

```
Session["progress"] = "Step Four";
```

**Client Side**:

Periodically call the action method and update an element on the page accordingly.

```
<script>
$.ajax('/Server/QueryStatus').done(function(response)
{
    $('#progressElement').innerHTML = response;
})


</script>
```